# distance between two space

Tags: functional-analysis

‎Given N- dimensional subspace ‎$W‎_{1}‎$ ‎and ‎‎$W‎_{2}‎‎$ ‎of a‎ ‎Hilbert ‎space‎, define the ‎$‎N$-tuple $(‎σ_{1},σ_{2},...,σ_{N}) $‎‎‎ as follows:

‎$$\sigma_{1}=\max \lbrace\langle a,b\rangle:a\in W_{1}‎ ,‎b\in W_{2},\Vert a\Vert=\Vert b\Vert=1\rbrace=\langle a_{1},b_{1}\rangle.$$‎
‏For ‎  $2\leqslant j\leqslant N$
‎$$ \sigma_{j}=\max \lbrace\langle a,b\rangle:\Vert a\Vert=\Vert b\Vert=1,\langle a_{k},a\rangle=0= \langle b_{k},b\rangle ~~~for ~~1\leqslant k\leqslant j-1\rbrace=\langle a_{j},b_{j}\rangle.$$‎ 
where $\langle a,b\rangle$ is innear product between a,b.

‎$N$-tuple $(θ_{1},θ_{2},...,θ_{N}) $‎  with ‎$θ_{j }=\cos^{-1}(σ_{j}) $‎  is called the principle angle between  ‎$ W_{1}‎$ , ‎‎$‎‎‎W_{2} $‎.

The chordal distance between  ‎$ W_{1}‎$ , ‎‎$‎‎‎W_{2} $‎ is given by

‎$$ d^{2}_{c}( W_{1},W_{2})=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sin^{2}\theta_{j}.$$‎

Let  ‎$ W_{1}‎$ be plane XY and  ‎‎$‎‎‎W_{2} $ be plane XZ determine distance between  ‎$ W_{1}‎$ , ‎‎$‎‎‎W_{2} $‎?

‎
‏